# Node Jest Axios Not Being Mocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, axios

`test.js`

```
const fn = require("./module.js")

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  create: () => {
     return {
       get() {
         return true
       }
    }
  },
  get: () => true
}))

it('should be mocked', async () => {
  const res = await fn()
  expect(res).toEqual(true)
})
```

`module.js`

```
const axios = require('axios')

exports.default = () => {
  const agent = axios.create();
  // Network error here because it is attempting to reach an endpoint
  // that is not valid. 
  return agent.get()
}
```

In summation, I receiving a network error from my axios request because it is an invalid network call that I am trying to prevent by mocking the service. Axios refuses to be mocked.

Comment: Can you instead export `agent` instead? Then mock/stub `get` or any other methods on agent you are trying to intercept in your tests? Also it looks like you are exporting an executed `get()`, rather than `get` function itself. How is that module being used exactly?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I think that's what I'm gonna do unfortunately.